How to add CORS headers to error pages in nginx?
I have configured CORS headers for my location, but when an error is triggered by nginx (e.g. because of client_max_body_size) the CORS headers are not added, so the client has no clue what it did wrong. How can I add CORS headers to the error pages?
A bit of googling lead me to this:
error_page 400 401 403 404 413 500 = @generic_error;

location @generic_error {
    internal;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type, Authorization';
    return $upstream_status;
}

However, I want it to apply to all error messages. The answers in nginx: Is it possible to have an 'catch all' error_page? suggest that this would be a bad idea, but I am not really sure why. I feel like I am missing something.
